# Biztalk 278 5010 schema v 217 and v 216

Tags: biztalk, edi

Our client is sending `278 5010 v 216` and `v 217` files in one `EDI` File. But `5010 Microsoft EDI Schema` only has `v 217`.

I would like to know specific customization steps to make the `v 217` schema work for `216` files also. I saw a comment from Ben Cline to remove additions for `x217` features. Can somebody elaborate on this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the regular X12 278 in the EDI\X12\00501 folder?  I think that's actually the 216 version as defined by X12.

217 is the HIPAA version of the same transaction, 278, but they're different.

Comment: X12 schema structure and HIPPA schema structure are different. Our mappings use HIPAA Schema structure by making use of the 2000A_Loop, 2000B_Loop etc. Is there any way we can customize the HIPAA schema to take v217 and v216 file for 5010 278 EDI files